# Why do DynamoDB imported size and actual table size differ so much?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have imported a DynamoDB table from S3. Here are the dataset sizes at each step:

- Compressed dataset in S3 (DynamoDB JSON format with GZIP compression) = 13.3GB
- Imported table size according to the [DynamoDB imports page](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbv2/home#imports) (uncompressed) = 64.4GB

  - Imported item count = 376 736 126
- Current table size according to the [DynamoDB tables page](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbv2/home#tables) (compressed?) = 41.5GB (**less than at the import time!**)

  - Item count = 380 528 674 (I have performed some insertions already)

Since the import time, the table was only growing.

**What's the reason of a much lesser estimation of the actual table size?** Is it because of an approximation of DynamoDB tables sizes in general? Or does DynamoDB apply any compression to the stored data?

The source S3 dataset should not have any duplicates: it is built using Athena by running a `GROUP BY` query on the DynamoDB table's key. So, I do not expect it to be a cause.

Each item has 4 attributes: PK is 2 long strings (blockchain addresses = 40 hex chars + extra ≈2–6 characters) + 1 long string (uint256 balance as a hex string ≤ 64 characters) + 1 numeric value. Table import format is DynamoDB JSON.

Comment: It is possible that DynamoDB applies some compression to the stored data. DynamoDB stores data in a binary format, which may offer some compression. However, the compression ratio may vary depending on the data stored in the table. It is also possible that the table size estimations on the DynamoDB page are not always accurate.

Comment: @Bawantha any details about the internal binary format? Tried to google for it with no luck. I have thought the same that it might be an internal format-specific optimization too, but have found no confirmation yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in the **DynamoDB JSON format's overhead**. I am the author of the question, so an exact example should provide more clarity. Here is a random item I have:

```json
{"Item":{"w":{"S":"65b88d0d0a1223eb96bccae06317a3155bc7e391"},"sk":{"S":"43ac8b882b7e06dde7c269f4f8aaadd5801bd974_"},"b":{"S":"6124fee993bc0000"},"n":{"N":"12661588"}}}
```

When imports from S3, DynamoDB import functionality bills per the *total read* uncompressed size. Which for this item results in **169 bytes** (168 chars + newline).

However, **when stored to DynamoDB, this item only occupies its fields capacity** (see [DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html)):

> - The size of a string is (length of attribute name) + (number of UTF-8-encoded bytes).
> - The size of a number is approximately (length of attribute name) + (1 byte per two significant digits) + (1 byte).

For this specific item the DynamoDB's native size estimation is:

- `w` (string) = 1 + 40 chars
- `sk` (string) = 2 + 41 chars
- `b` (string) = 1 + 16 chars
- `n` (number) = 1 + (8 significant digits / 2 = 4) + 1

Total is **107 bytes**. Actually, current DynamoDB's estimation for this table is 108.95 bytes per item on average which is pretty close (some fields values vary in length, this particular example is nearly the shortest possible).

This results in about 100% – 108.95 / 169 = **35% size reduction when the data is actually stored in DynamoDB** compared to the imported size. Which is very close to the results I have reported in the question: 64.4GB * 108.95 / 169 = 40.39GB ≈ 41.5GB.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB performs no compression.

The likely cause is how you are calculating the size of the table and number of items. If you are relying on the tables metadata, it is only updated every 6 hours and is an approximate value, which should not be relied upon for comparisons or validity checks.